# i am submitting a form which has two files and doing a ajax post request. But i am not able to get the file in my django view

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, file

I am able to do a post request but not able to retrive the files in my django view.

This is the ajax post request performed on button click

```
$("#upload-button").on('click', function() {
 var formdata = new FormData();
 var idElementForFiles = 'file1-to-upload';
 var uploadedFiles = document.getElementById(idElementForFiles);
 formdata.append("metadata_name",uploadedFiles.files[0].name);
 formdata.append("metadata", uploadedFiles.files[0]);
 var idElementForFiles = 'file2-to-upload';
 var uploadedFiles = document.getElementById(idElementForFiles);
 formdata.append("name",uploadedFiles.files[0].name);
 formdata.append("file", uploadedFiles.files[0]);
 var csrfmiddlewaretoken= document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')    [0].value;
formdata.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrfmiddlewaretoken);
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: '/submit',
   processData:false,
   contentType:false,
   data : {
       "formdata" :formdata,
       "value":"testing",
   },
   "beforeSend": function(xhr, settings)
   {
     console.log("Before Send");
     $.ajaxSettings.beforeSend(xhr, settings);
   },
   cache: false,
   success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(errorThrown);}
  });
 });
```

code to retrive the files in my views.py which is not working

```
def save_files(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      v=request.POST.get("value")
      fs = FileSystemStorage()
   # get the PDF file and save it
     file1 = request.FILES['file']
     filename1 = file1.name
     fs.save((os.path.join("static","pdf_files",filename1)), file1)

     #fs.save(os.path.join("static","pdf_files",filename1))

     file2 = request.FILES['metadata']
     filename2 = file2.name
     fs.save((os.path.join("static","metadata_files",filename2)), file2)
   return HttpResponse("its working")
```

Comment: what code is not working? please write question more in detail.

Comment: im unable to retrive the files from my view. Im getting error in this line file1=request.FILES['file'] in my views.py file

Comment: i figured it out. the error was in the data field in the ajax call it should be     $.ajax({data:formdata});

Comment: Great! Problem solved? good to hear that!